# There is a missing project subtype error when I try to create a new sharepoint addin project

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I get an error whenever I try to create a new SharePoint 2013 (on premise asp.net MVC) Add-in project using Visual studio Enterprise 2017 RC as follows:

there is a missing project subtype. Subtype: '{14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079}' is unsupported by this installation.

How do I fix this problem so that I can create SharePoint Add-in projects for my company's intranet website?

Regards

Comment: This solution pointed me in the right direction to fix the problem. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2014/04/08/problem-solved-visual-studio-there-is-a-missing-project-subtype-subtype-82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60-is-unsupported-by-this-installation/

Answer (score 1):

This solution pointed me in the right direction to fix the problem. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2014/04/08/problem-solved-visual-studio-there-is-a-missing-project-subtype-subtype-82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60-is-unsupported-by-this-installation/

I went back to Visual Studio 2015 and updated my Nuget package. Now I am using VS 2015 to create SharePoint Add-in projects.